# .htaccess - Exclude folder from basic auth protection

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, http-basic-authentication

I have a website where no one is allowed to enter without entering the basic auth credentials.

However, I need the media folder to be accessible by everyone, because we are using a third party extension which creates PDF's and we can only fully test them if the media is accessible.

The media folder is at `/var/www/company/pub/media`.

The domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) points to `/var/www/company/pub`, so the **pub** folder is the entry point.

This is my .htaccess attempt (`/var/www/company/.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/company/.htpasswd"

# Exclude media folder from basic auth
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/media/*" media

Order allow,deny
Require valid-user
Allow from env=media
Deny from env=!media
Satisfy any
```

But if I try to call *http://www.example.com/media/someimage.jpg* then I still get the basic auth login prompt.

**Environment:**

Apache 2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> # Exclude media folder from basic auth
> SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/media/*" media
>
> Order allow,deny
> Require valid-user
> Allow from env=media
> Deny from env=!media
> Satisfy any
> ```

This would have worked, except the regex is wrong in the `SetEnvIf` directive, so the env var `media` is not set when requesting `/media/someimage.jpg`. You are missing a dot before the `*` quantifier, ie. `^/media/.*`. However, you can just remove the trailing `*` altogether, ie. `^/media/`, which is effectively the same (and more efficient).

The `Deny from env=!media` directive is superfluous.

So, the following should work:

```
# Exclude media folder from basic auth
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/media/" media

Require valid-user
 
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=media
Satisfy Any
```

HOWEVER, this is using deprecated Apache 2.2 directives. On Apache 2.4 you can do the following instead:

```
# Exclude media folder from basic auth
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/media/" media

Require valid-user
Require env media
```

The *default* container is `<RequireAny>` - so you don't need to include this. Although you can be explicit if you want:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require valid-user
    Require env media
</RequireAny>
```

---

Alternatively, you can surround the entire authorization block in an `<If>` expression. For example:

```
# Password protect everything except the "/media/" subdirectory
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/media/#">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected"
    AuthUserFile "/var/www/company/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

The operator `!~` is a negated regular expression match.

Comment: Nice, I tried it and everything works. I accept your answer instead, since it contains more helpful details and shows why my attempt failed.

Answer (score 9):

Place a .htaccess file in the media folder with `AuthType None`.

```
AuthType None
Require all granted
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thx!